# Changing i3 startup terminal

Tags: arch-linux, window-manager, i3

In my .bashrc, I set the TERMINAL variable:

```
export TERMINAL=termite
```

as a result, i3's `exec i3-sensible-terminal` can find my terminal emulator (termite) and open it when I press `$mod+Return`. However, for some reason, xterm is still started when i3 starts, as the status terminal that prints messages from i3. I start i3 with `xinit i3`, which I type in to my textmode shell when I want to open i3. How can I change the initial terminal from xterm to termite to match my other setting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run `xinit i3` you will simply add `i3` to the default X11 client of `xterm`, i.e. you will start `xterm i3`. To show you want to replace the default client completely you need to use the full path to your program, e.g.

```
xinit /usr/bin/i3
```

See `man xinit`.